# ggsave does not print minus symbol after creating plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pdf

i am triyng to get in the y label of my plot a formula which includes a minus,but the way I am doing it does not include the - symbol.
I will give a reproducible example here:

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars
plot1ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  ylab(expression(paste("test ", "(A – B)"/"c")))
```

When I do:

```
ggsave(plot1, filename = "./Figures/pdf/test.pdf", units = "mm", width = 180, height = 70)
```

I get this in the figure: (A ..B/c)
How can I get the right symbol in the figure?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `cairo_pdf` as device like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  ylab(expression(paste("test ", "(A – B)"/"c"))) 

ggsave(plot1, filename = "test.pdf", units = "mm", width = 180, height = 70, device = cairo_pdf)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: it works thanks! and for ggsave in png? is there a similar option?